# Django Bad request error when trying to log in

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a LoginAPIView in my django project and it works as intended but it says "Bad Request: /login/" and I'm worried since it may cause some problems in the future.

views.py:

```
class LoginAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = LoginAPISerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)

        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({'token': token.key}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializer.py:

```
class LoginAPISerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')

        if not username or not password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Username and password are required')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid credentials')

        data['user'] = user
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return {'token': token.key}
```

I looked up for solutions but I couldn't find one. Please help, thanks.

Comment: By it works as intended do you mean you get validation errors when you submit invalid data?  Responses returned for validation errors have status code 400, which is "Bad Request".  The logs are basically just telling you the status code it returned, which "Bad Request".